How does UrlShortx works
Not Like link other shortener websites that create a shortened link but how does the UrlShortx redirect to the original link
I've seen the URL workflow as
shortened link ->
Checks for redirection ->
if: no -> redirects to several third-party(blog) 
  links wait for about 10..15 seconds on each site
  (links like "https://blog.com/how-to-code" without a search query)
  then redirects back to the shortened link
Checks for redirection again -> original link

I want to know how the backend works here
